# how to know whether bindingsource/dataset in insert mode

Tags: c#, winforms

Uses: Oracle 9i, VS 2005, .Net Framework 2.0+, MDAC 2.7+, Winforms;

In Borland Delphi, one can know the Data Source's State (i.e TTable, TADOTabale etc) by using the "State" Method. i.e

If one needs to know whether the Table is in Insert State then I can write a program something similar to below

```
If table1.State = dsInsert Then
begin
//Do work
end;
```

Similarly, Is there any equivalent method where I can find the State, particularly whether its in "Insert" state from DataSet, DataTable or BindingSource objects in .Net Framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can check state on `DataRow` level using property `RowState`.

[Here's msdn documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx)

You can also check for specific type of modyfications in DataTable using:

```
DataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState)
```

> If no rows of the desired DataRowState are found, the method returns
>   null

[Here's msdn documentation for that.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/0f8054fy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if Im wrong, There is no method to find the state ether *update* or *insert* in `DataSet` with `BindingSource`, but you could insert, update or delete base on the  *primary key* from the table.

*Example:*

```
if (Id > 0)
  //TODO: Update
else
  //TODO: Insert
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in my case where the ID is not an auto-generated column, instead the user should enter a value. Had the scenario been with an Auto-Generated Column, your solution will work.

Comment: yes, but it is necessarily to use the primary key in our table. but anyway.. you must get the `ID` in your table so you can update or delete the data.